# How to check performance time in java/kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to check the performance time.

I have an android app, but there is a claim about the performance.

So I am researching where is the slow part.

To do this, I add some logs like below:

```
fun methodA() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start... ")

    // my business logic

    Log.d(TAG, "end... ")
}
```

So I can find the run time of the method.

But now, I want to know how to get the run time of the library method?

In the case of my app code, I can add the logging.
But I don't know how to check the library.

Is there any good solution?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code in kotlin:

```
measureTimeMillis{
    methodA()
}
```

measureTimeMillis (as well as measureNanoTime) is a standard library function

Answer (score 0):

you can check performance time in Profiler tab in Android Studio which is located above the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

**KOTLIN INLINE SOLUTION**

Late for OP but may help others.

*This solution will help folks who want to log and execute function inline same time after execution completes, also is a cleaner approach when there is multiple performance measurement involved of different functions*

Create functions as such:

```
//the inline performance measurement method
private inline fun <T> measurePerformanceInMS(
        logger: (Long) -> Unit,
        function: () -> T)
: T {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result: T = function.invoke()
    val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    logger.invoke( endTime - startTime)
    return result
}

//the logger function
fun logPerf(time: Long){
    Log.d("TAG","PERFORMANCE IN MS: $time ms ")
}

//the function whose performance needs to be checked
fun longRunningFunction() : Int{
    var x = 0
    for (i in 1..20000) x++
    return x
}
```

This way you can keep logging, performance computation and function execution under a single function call and no code replication needed.

If you require nano second measurement then use `System.nanoTime()`

**USAGE** :

```
val endResult = measurePerformanceInMS({time -> logPerf(time)}){
            longRunningFunction()
        }
```

**NOTE** : here the *'endResult'* will carry the result of function whose performance was being measured.